# Camera does not open on HTC devices

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I have built a Camera based on the code example presented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) and have enhanced it with the Camera.java and ShutterButton.java from AOSP GingerBread,the code I took away was mostly for the autofocus and for the ShutterButton.The Camera has been tested on `Samsung Galaxy Nexus` and the `Samsung Galaxy S4` and the `LG Optimus` Phone running 4.0.x and it works.However,upon testing at appthwack.com the results are [here](https://appthwack.com/project/scancard/run/36297/jobrun/3430276).This was my Camera.open code which was not working:

```
    try{   
         Camera.open();
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
          Log.e(TAG,"Could not open camera",ex);//running on HTC prints could not open camera
       }
   mPreview=new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);//this is which the NullPointerException is thrown
```

The above code is called in the Activity's onResume which means that the Camera object is only in use when the screen is visible to the user,I release the Camera in onPause() like this:

```
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    isPreviewShowing=false;
    if(mCamera!=null)
    killCamera();
    container.removeAllViews();

     private void killCamera()
{
    if(mCamera!=null)
    {
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera=null;
    }
}
```

I have changed the code for opening the camera to:

```
 Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();
    int cameraCount=mCamera.getNumberOfCameras();
    int cameraIndex=0;
    for(cameraIndex=0;cameraIndex<cameraCount;cameraIndex++)
    {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, info);
        if(info.facing==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
        {
            try
            {
                mCamera=Camera.open(cameraIndex);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not open camera",ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

This did not work either,I have also tried adding the following code to the `CameraPreview` class that has:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CameraPreview(Context context,Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.ctx=context;
    mCamera=camera;
    mHolder=this.getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

    @Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if(mCamera==null)
    {
        mCamera=null;
        Camera.CameraInfo info=new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount=mCamera.getNumberOfCameras();
        int cameraIndex=0;
        for(cameraIndex=0;cameraIndex<cameraCount;cameraIndex++)
        {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, info);
            if(info.facing==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            {
                try
                {
                    mCamera=Camera.open(cameraIndex);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not open camera",ex);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    try
    {
        if(mCamera==null)
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"Camera is null here but why???");
        }
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("CameraPreview","Error getting camera preview",e);
    }
}
```

This did not work either.Also,for anyone asking me about permissions,I have declared all the requisite permissions as:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"
     />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
              android:required="true"
     />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer"
              android:required="true"
    />
```

It would be a little difficult to get started working on a brand new Camera,I would like to(if possible) keep the existing structure of the Camera intact,so could you please help me sort this issue out.The entire logcat file is available along with the test results posted above.

## EDIT:

Using the global SurfaceHolder Object instead of the holder on holder provider by surfaceCreated solves the issue on HTC Desire HD but not on HTC One S.It throws the error here:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at 
 com.blutechnologies.scancard.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:95) at   
 android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:543) at 
 android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81) at 
 android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169) at 
 android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1793) at 
 android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2700) at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at 
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) at 
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is preceeded by:

```
 I  ActivityManager START {cmp=com.blutechnologies.scancard/.CameraActivity} from pid 21085
 I  QualcommCamera  Qint android::get_camera_info(int, camera_info*): E
 V  QCameraHAL  void android::HAL_getCameraInfo(int, android::CameraInfo*): E
 V  QCameraHAL  void android::HAL_getCameraInfo(int, android::CameraInfo*): X
```

I guess it means that the Camera is busy,that is it is being used elsewhere,is it due to a previous crash on the device,would it rectify itself if I put the camera closing code in `surfaceDestroyed`,doing that seems extremely dangerous,I added this code to my surfaceDestroyed:

```
  private void killCamera()
{
    if(mCamera!=null)
    {
        mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera=null;
    }
}
```

The Camera is now blank and does not show a preview at all,it gets stuck at setting the Preview Size.There must be some thing I am not doing that can solve this error.

Comment: has permission,camera working on GNexus,Samsung GS4

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException at  com.blutechnologies.scancard.CameraPreview.surfaceCreated(CameraPreview.java:82)` can you post whole java file

Comment: there are in fact two java files,one for the preview and another for the Activity,I will post the open for the preview [first](http://pastebin.com/QMk4PquB)

Comment: `HTC Desire HD` and `HTC One S`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43871/discussion-between-chintan-khetiya-and-user2309862)

Comment: If anyone would like to see an older version of my CameraActivity,[here](http://pastebin.com/J475cdQ6) it is,my CameraPreview is [here](http://pastebin.com/QMk4PquB)

Answer (score 2):

This is example how to get camera:

```
 private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        int cameraCount = 0;
        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
            if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK  ) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.e("Camera", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        return cam;
    }
```

And also check the permissions in manifest

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I do not need `android.hardware.camera.front` but the rest permissions are already in my manifest.Modified the code as per your suggestion.Is there a way to test this,I am running out of appThwack minutes

Comment: tried getting the camera almost exactly as you suggested...did not work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the exact issue , but you are writing your code on `surfaceCreated` but i have some other technique.

```
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean previewing = false;

**OnCreate** 
...
...

getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

**OnPreviewStart()**

```
OnPreviewStart() {
    if (!previewing) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**onPreviewStop()**

```
onPreviewStop() {
               if (camera != null && previewing) {
                   camera.stopPreview();
                   camera.release();
                   camera = null;

                   previewing = false;
               }
       }
```

You can call above two function wherever you want to use , to show & Preview of camera on surface.

Next thing `implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`

That will @Override three method for surface few like

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height){}
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){}
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){}
```

[Check for more detail.](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/camera-preview-in-android/)

Comment: Why use `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);`

Comment: you can remove that line

Comment: Also you seem to be doing the code in `onClick` after loading an Activity in the sample you code,could you try by moving your `onPreviewStart` code into `surfaceCreated` or changing the method into `onPreviewStart(SurfaceHolder holder)` and try with the `holder` given to you by `surfaceCreated`,I wonder if the `holder` is null by calling it here.

Comment: Using your version i.e changing to mHolder instead of holder works on HTC Desire HD but it does not work on the HTC One S